# php include results in page being written in pre

Tags: php, html, include, pre

I'm learning php, been trying to make a cms, but when I use an include for the header this results in the page appearing as if it were written in pre tags. There's no errors when I debug or anything. And I'm completely stumped. When I put the header back in without the include it renders just fine.

```
<?php include("..\includes\layouts\header.php"); ?>
```

That's the include I'm using.
I've tried using the full path name, tried it in different browsers and using :

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

Comment: Is `header.php` sending a `Content-type` header?

Comment: What is _actually_ sent to the browser? What's in the page source? How did you call this PHP  page? Are you running a web server, and does the parent PHP script have a .php extension?

Comment: The page source is exactly the same as the webpage. Page name is manage_content.php, I'm running xampp and the parent file is php as well.

Comment: @user3199449 when you reply to a comment on stack overflow, use the @ symbol and they will get a notification that you have responded to their message. That way they know to come back to your question. Just a heads up

Comment: @ Barmar in the header.php file is :
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Widget Corp</title>
 <link href="C:\xampp\htdocs\widget_corp1\public\stylesheets\public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
 <h1>Widget Corp</h1>
</div>'

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are closing your php tags, ending your strings with semi colons etc.. My guess is that your html is being sucked into the php code which freaks out and just dumps it.

Maybe try one of the validators such as http://phpcodechecker.com (I have not used this one so I cannot comment on it's effectiveness)

**Edit:** I am rereading your post and I think I understand what you are trying to say - your header contains the path to your css and when you put it in a separate php file the css doesn't work?  So the first thing to do is determine if the issue with the php path or the css path inside the header.php file. Look at your source code to see if the header code is being included - if it is then play around with the css path - though including the header in a php file will not cause that css path to change.

I am guessing that your header is not included at all from your mention of paths. include() works from the loading file's location. The path it wants is a server path and not a url. The one that you have above: `../includes...` means that you have an include folder at the same level as the loading file such as (assume index.php is the main file):

```
/includes/layouts/header.php
/somedirectory/index.php
```

The `../` means - drop down one directory then go up from there.

If your path is more like:

```
/includes/layouts/header.php
/index.php
```

Then the include would be:

```
include('./includes/layouts/header.php');
```

Let me know if that works - if it doesn't try to explain your directory structure.

Comment: Tried the codechecker, said it found no fault. I'm following one of the lynda courses. I've even got the exercise files and the same thing happens to them as well. It's just weird, it's like it won't read the css file.

Comment: What exactly is showing on screen that should not? html, css, php? Not sure what you mean by css file in relation your question - are you saying your html is all there but it's just not styled? or are you seeing html tags displayed literally?